# calling parent constructor inside child constructor

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am just curious to know that if its a good idea to create a child class constructor just for calling parent constructor.

```
class A {
  public function __construct() {
      echo 'I am in: '.__CLASS__.'<br/>';
  }
  public function getData() {
      echo 'I am in: '.__METHOD__.'<br/>';
  }
}

class B extends A {

  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      echo 'I am in: '.__CLASS__.'<br/>';
  }

  public function getDataFromB(){
      echo 'I am in: '.__METHOD__.'<br/>';
  }
}

$objB = new B();
$objB->getDataFromB();
```

Now in following example we can achieve the same:

```
class A {
  public function __construct() {
      echo 'I am in: '.__CLASS__.'<br/>';
    }
  public function getData() {
      echo 'I am in: '.__METHOD__.'<br/>';
    }
}

class B extends A {
  public function getDataFromB(){
      echo 'I am in: '.__METHOD__.'<br/>';
    }
}

$objB = new B();
$objB->getDataFromB();
```

## Question:

Is it a good idea to create a child constructor only for invoking parent constructor or there are any other advantages of doing so?

Comment: It's simply superfluous, period.

Comment: The parent constructor will automatically be called if you don't override it in the child class. So unless you plan on implementing additional functionality, then it's pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `__construct` calls in classes is:

1. If class has its' own `__construct` - it will be called
2. If class does not have its' own `__construct` - parent `__construct` (if it exists) will be called.

So, if you create a `__construct` in a child class, parent `__construct` **will not be called** unless you explicitly point it with `parent::__construct()`.

So, if nothing serious will happen in a child `__construct` - you can omit it and parent `__construct` will be called.

On the other side - if you do some additional initialization or other actions in child `__construct`, then it will not call `parent::__construct` unless you explicitly point it.

Comment: Not just `__construct`, this is the same behaviour of all methods…

Comment: @deceze sure, but here we talk about `__construct`